# Converting params to JSON and passing as argument to ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

I'm upgrading a rails 4.2 app to Rails 5 and I'm no longer able to pass params like [:members][:contact_ids]  into ActiveJob.

I've tried to convert to json like

```
contact_ids = [:members][:contact_ids].to_json
CreateMemberJob.perform_later(organization, contact_ids)
```

Which turns it into

```
   "[22,14,18]"
```

but once it's passed through active job, it becomes

```
 "[\"\",\"22\",\"14\",\"18\"]"
```

How do I return this to an array of IDs.

When I try .to_a I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_a' for  ""[\"\",\"22\",\"14\",\"18\"]"":String
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following:

```
contact_ids = ["22","14","18"].to_json
=> "[\"22\",\"14\",\"18\"]"

contact_ids.delete!('"')
=> "[22,14,18]"

JSON.parse(contact_ids)
=> [22, 14, 18]
```